# Pandas regular expression processing of column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to clean text columns in my dataframe using a re library.

each column contains individual sentences to be cleaned.

For the example I put together this guy:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import re

def remove_url(text):
    return re.sub(r'Dinn', '', text)

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')

df.assign(text = lambda d: remove_url(d['time']))
# df.assign(text = lambda d: remove_url(str(d['time'])))
# df.assign(text = lambda d: remove_url(d['time'].str))
```

All of the suggested approaches via `assign` and `lambda` seem not to be working. In another cases they do however it duplicates first-row text into all rows.

What is the preferred way of achieving this ideally using `assign` and not pandas `apply`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
df.assign(text=df['time'].apply(lambda x: remove_url(x)))


     total_bill   tip     sex smoker   day    time  size text
0         16.99  1.01  Female     No   Sun  Dinner     2   er
1         10.34  1.66    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     3   er
2         21.01  3.50    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     3   er
3         23.68  3.31    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     2   er
4         24.59  3.61  Female     No   Sun  Dinner     4   er
..          ...   ...     ...    ...   ...     ...   ...  ...
```

The problem with your code was that you didn't use the apply function correctly.